# App delegate point to unknown exception

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

How is it possible to clear off this problem

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)

I tried adding Facebook sign-in and Google sign-in into my app yet facing lots of problem on the way. Google sign-in works perfectly fine but not for Facebook, I followed all instructions but still this error won't go away.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

           // Set navigation bar custom background color
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent


         GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
         GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self


        // Set up Google services api key
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("---{**KEY**}---")
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("---{**KEY**}----")


             FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)


        // Use firebase library to configure APIs
        FIRApp.configure()

        return true
    }


    // Invokes handle URL method of the GIDSignIn & FBSDK Login instance  @Available (iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        let googleSignInHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        let facebookSignInHandle = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return googleSignInHandle || facebookSignInHandle

    }
```

Anyone can help ?

Comment: Can you add a more descriptive error message?

Comment: On what line does this occur? It's recommended that you put a breakpoint on NSExceptions. This article should help: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: @nighttalker @colin-basnett Here's the complete error message  `Terminating app due to uncaught 'invalidOperationException', reason: ** Facebook Id ** is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist.`   and yes i did try following the instructions given on facebook console yet nothing seem to work.

Comment: Managed to solve, i had to manually add my Facebook App id into URL scheme with eg: fb238928282349